# How can you proove that every bounded function in $L^1[0;1]$ can be approximated by continuous function in $C[0;1]$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, approximation

Here my question, is this true that:

> Every bounded function in $L^1[0;1]$ can be approximated by continuous functions in $C[0;1]$

It seems to me true as we know that $C[0;1]$ is dense in $L^1[0;1]$, but **without using** it (the density of $C[0;1]$ in $L^1[0;1]$) how can i proove it?

Thank you.

EDIT: **i CAN'T use the fact that C[0;1] is dense in L1[0;1]**

Comment: @MarkViola Thk. No because i CAN'T use the fact that $C[0;1]$ is dense in $L^1[0;1]$. (Or i didn't understant what you meant by your answer)

Comment: approximate a characteristic function $\chi_{[a,b]}$ with continuous functions and work from there

Comment: @Targon Thank you for you answer. I thought about it too to first proove that $ \forall \varepsilon >0 $ we can approximate $ 1_{|x|} \leq \varepsilon $ by a serie of continous function (for exemple fourrier serie). But i have a problem if the indicator function has an infinity number of discontinuing points

Comment: @Targon I devellop an answer base on your comment, if you can check it and told me if it is correct i will appreciate.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be the closure of $C[0,1]$ in $L^1[0,1]$. You want to show that $\mathscr{C}=L^1[0,1]$. In order to prove this, we shall assume the contrary and reach a contradiction. Assuming that $\mathscr{C}\ne L^1[0,1]$ gives the existence of a non-zero continuous linear functional $f^*\in L^1[0,1]^*$ that vanishes on $C[0,1]$. Every $f^*\in L^1[0,1]^*$ may be written as
$$
       f^*(g)=\int_0^1g(t)f(t)dt,\;\; g\in L^1,
$$
for a unique $f\in L^\infty[0,1]$. By assumption $f^*(g)=0$ for all $g\in C[0,1]$. By a simple limiting argument, it is easy to show that $f^*(\chi_{[0,c]})=0$ for all $0 \le c \le 1$, which gives
$$
           \int_0^c f(t)dt=0,\;\; 0 \le c \le 1.
$$
By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, it follows that $f=0$ a.e.. However, this contradicts the assumption that $f^* \ne 0$, which proves that $\mathscr{C}=L^1[0,1]$, which is to say that the closure of $C[0,1]$ in $L^1[0,1]$ is $L^1[0,1]$. And that gives you what you wanted to prove.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer!!

Comment: @X0-user-0X : You are most welcome.